# Разные времена глаголов в одном предложении: ошибка или норма?

Tags: грамотная-речь, глаголы, спп, времена

Как я понимаю, в русском языке нет какого-то жесткого требования к согласованию времен между главным и придаточным предложениями. Но, допустим, речь идет о каком-нибудь романе, где повествование всегда ведется в прошедшем времени. Верны ли будут в нем такие предложения:
*Она обернулась и увидела, что к мосту приближается та самая фигура.* (Или лучше "приближалась"?)

*Именинница догадалась, что гости прошли в дальний зал и теперь ждут ее там.* (Допустимо ли использование слова "теперь", которое, по сути, указывает на то, что действие происходит в настоящем?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все конструкции абсолютно верны.

> Но, допустим, речь идет о каком-нибудь романе, где повествование
>   всегда ведется в прошедшем времени

Вот уж точно, все беды - от неправильно понятых догм. Нет такого правила, что всё повествование должно вестись в одном времени. Нельзя *беспричинно* менять грамматическое время в связанном тексте, это да. Но если разумная причина есть, то почему нет?!

Конкретно по вашим примерам и вопросам к ним. Вы не путайте время основного повествования и время придаточного или зависимого предложения. В огромном большинстве случаев это второе время - относительно. Оно соответствует времени на момент основного действия.

Сравните в прямой и косвенной речи.

*Я сказал: "Я его вижу".*
и
*Я сказал: "Я его видел".*

Есть разница?
При этом первый вариант возможно (хотя и не обязательно) передавать в косвенной конструкции как "Я сказал, что я его вижу". Сомнений не возникает, что это происходит в момент, когда говорящий эту фразу произносит. У вас абсолютно те же случаи, только много всяких слов, которые на рассматриваемую проблему никак не влияют.

> Она обернулась и увидела, что к мосту приближается та самая фигура.
>   (или лучше "приближалась"?)

Хуже. Получается, что фигура приближалась раньше, не в момент, когда "она" посмотрела. Можно, конечно, двояко трактовать, но исходный-то авторский вариант двусмысленности точно не несёт.

> Именинница догадалась, что гости прошли в дальний зал и теперь ждут ее
>   там. (Допустимо ли использование слова "теперь", которое, по сути,
>   указывает на то, что действие происходит в настоящем?)

А вот тут вообще непонятно, в каком "физическом" времени происходит. Но допустим, вы это знаете из контекста. Так и что? Она догадалась (Ну пусть это буде в прошлом "физическом") - что именно? Что "теперь" (на *тот момент*, когда гости *уже* прошли и она *уже* догадалась) они ждут её в зале. Как еще можно тут построить *грамматическое* время? "Теперь ждали"? "Тогда ждали"? А когда "тогда"?

Тут не то что можно, тут просто необходимо использовать подобную конструкцию, чтобы не влезать в дебри многоэтажных объяснений, когда именно то-то и то-то произошло.

Кстати, именно это представление об относительности грамматического времени в русском языке, работающее не только в рассмотренных конструкциях, но и в целом ряде других (для причастий и деепричастий, к примеру), частично компенсирует крайнюю бедность системы грамматических времен русского языка, почти или полностью лишенного таких совершенно естественных для большинства других языков времен и аспектов, как перфект, давнопрошедшее время, аорист, "будущее в прошедшем" и многих других. А между прочим, именно в связи с  отсутствием таких форм и родилась рекомендация "не мешать времена". В английском бы от такой рекомендации просто открестились, ибо на каждый случай есть своя грамматическая форма, смешать их, оставаясь в рамках грамматики, невозможно. А у нас получилась, что правильная в общем-то рекомендация, будучи неверно истолкованной, приводит к обратному эффекту, затрудняя понимания текста.

Comment: В данном предложении "теперь ждали" точно выглядит инородно или просто некрасиво, но само словосочетание грамматически верно? Например, при таком построении предложения звучит неплохо: Они прошли в переднюю и теперь ждали его там. Так же можно написать?

Answer (score 2):

**Согласование времен верное.**

1) Действие происходят в прошлом, но для героя романа **это прошлое воспринимается как настоящее**. Поэтому: Она обернулась и увидела, что к мосту **приближается** та самая фигура.

А вот если автор описывает ту же ситуацию, то она скажет: К мосту приближалась та самая фигура.

**2) Аналогично во втором случае, герой воспринимает прошлое как настоящий момент:** гости уже прошли (действие закончено) и сейчас (в условно настоящий момент) ждут ее.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ. Пожалуйста, помогите добить мой заскок.  Будет ли правильным данное предложение: Они прошли в переднюю и теперь ждали его там. "Теперь ждали" - можно использовать такое словосочетание?

Comment: Предложение построено правильно. ТЕПЕРЬ, нареч. В настоящее время, в данный момент; сейчас, также в текущий момент, ныне. Наречие "теперь" относит время  действия к определенному моменту (в прошлом или настоящем). Сравните (без теперь): Они прошли в переднюю, ждали его там, а потом ушли