# Согласование времён

Tags: согласование

Как правильно: "Джина стояла, прижавшись лбом к прохладной поверхности стекла, и смотрела, как за окном умираЛ ещё один зимний день" или "Джина стояла, прижавшись лбом к прохладной поверхности стекла, и смотрела, как за окном умираЕТ ещё один зимний день"?

Comment: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431082/Разные-времена-глаголов-в-одном-предложении-ошибка-или-норма