# Нет ли здесь ошибок во видовременной соотнесённости?

Tags: глаголы, времена

*Я устал и хочу спать.*

*Я заболел и завтра не пойду на работу.*

Глаголы, используемые в этих предложениях, употреблены в разном времени, а в первом ещё и имеют разный вид. Но, несмотря на то, что встречающиеся мне правила требуют использования глаголов только в одном времени и виде, эти предложения кажутся нормальными и корректными. В чём же дело?

Comment: А какие вам попадались правила, указывающие на ГРАММАТИЧЕСКУЮ некорректность данных предложений?

Comment: я думаю, идет речь об однородных членах, но здесь не однородные члены, а сложносочиненные предложения. Я устал и (я) хочу спать~я устал, поэтому хочу спать. Я заболел и завтра (я) не пойду на работу~я заболел и поэтому завтра не пойду на работу. По-русски предложение может не иметь сказуемого: не пойду на работу, заболел, буду спать; заболел и не пойду - отстаньте.

Comment: Здесь однородные. см http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/textbooks/author/litnevskaya/part5#34101. Но мне не вопрос интересен, а логика вопрошающего. Ни слова об однородности (то бишь пунктуации), зато есть слова о корректном звучании (то бишь грамматике) и каких-то правилах, которые регулируют корректность.

Comment: Похожий вопрос  уже обсуждался: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/431082/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0

Comment: Это обычные школьные правила. Например, я видел такую формулировку: "Если в предложении встречаются несколько глагольных форм, будь то два сказуемых, или деепричастие и сказуемое, или причастие и сказуемое, — они в обязательном порядке должны соотноситься друг с другом по времени и виду".

Comment: Ещё есть такой момент: однородные члены в предложении должны отвечать на один вопрос. В приведённых мною примерах вопросы будут разными ("что сделал?" и "что делаю?"/"что буду делать?") — наталкивает на мысль, что это уже не однородные члены. Но в то же время запятая перед "и" не ставится, как было бы в случае наличия двух грамматических основ.